# C void function with return value

Tags: c

As far as I know, `return` statement in void function will throw an error.

But in the below program that is not the case.

Here the displayed output is `1`. How comes?

```
main()
{
    int i=5;
    printf("%d",fun(fun(fun(i))));
}

void fun(int i)
{
    if (i%2)
    {
        return (i+(7*4)-(5/2)+(2*2));
    }
    else
    {
        return (i+(17/5)-(34/15)+(5/2));
    }
}
```

Comment: Using `fun` before it has a prototype can have messy consequences. This implies it returns `int`, and who knows how that is resolved by the compiler when you define it later? This would be forbidden from C99 onwards.

Comment: in fact, this code snippet produces about as much lines of compiler warnings than it has relevant lines of code. never a good sign.

Comment: it's undefined behaviour. I get 1 without compiler optimization and 0 with compiler optimization.

Answer (score 7):

A `return` statement with no expression:

```
void func(void) {
    return;
}
```

is perfectly legal in a `void` function.  The legality of a `return` statement with an expression depends on the version of the C language you're using.

The 1990 C standard says:

> A **`return`** statement with an expression shall not appear in a
>   function whose return type is **`void`**.

The 1999 and 2011 editions of the standard both say:

> A **`return`** statement with an expression shall not appear
>   in a function whose return type is **`void`**. A **`return`**
>   statement without an expression shall only appear in a function
>   whose return type is **`void`**.

This is a *constraint*, meaning that a compiler must issue a diagnostic (possibly a non-fatal warning) for any program that violates it.

C90 permitted a `return` statement with no expression in a non-`void` function for historical reasons. Pre-ANSI C did not have the `void` keyword, so there was no way to define a function that didn't return a value. Programmers would omit the return type (which would default to `int`) and simply ignore it. The C90 rule allowed such old code to compile without error. You could still fail to return a value from a non-`void` function; the program's behavior is undefined if a caller attempts to use the (nonexistent) result. The 1999 standard tightened up the rules a bit.

Another problem with your program is that you call `fun` before its declaration is visible. Under C99 and later rules, this is illegal (though a compiler might merely warn about it). Under C90 rules, this is legal, but the compiler will assume that the function returns `int`. Your program's behavior is undefined, but your `void` function `fun` might happen to behave as if it returned a value, and a call to it might happen to behave as if it used that value.

C compilers tend to be fairly lax about some errors, so that old code (sometimes written before the first actual standard was published) will not be rejected. But your compiler *should* have at least warned you about the `return` statement, and probably about the invalid call. You should pay close attention to compiler warnings; they should be treated almost the same way as fatal errors. And you should use options to increase the number of things your compiler warns you about. If you're using gcc, use `-std=c90`, `-std=c99`, or `-std=c11`, along with `-pedantic` to enforce standard conformance. You can add `-Wall`-Wextra` to enable more warnings.

Comment: I donot know whether it is good or bad but sometimes I use quite a lot "empty" returns in void returning functions.

Comment: @JewelThief: That's perfectly valid. Though as a matter of good design *some* people advocate writing functions so they return from only one point; early `return`s, with or without a value, can make the control flow more difficult to analyze.

Answer (score 4):

The code you've presented is actually invalid in C99 for a variety of reasons, but the most painful one is below:

```
foo.c:5:17: warning: implicit declaration of function 'fun' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    printf("%d",fun(fun(fun(i))));
                ^
foo.c:8:6: error: conflicting types for 'fun'
void fun(int i)
     ^
foo.c:5:17: note: previous implicit declaration is here
    printf("%d",fun(fun(fun(i))));
                ^
```

Note that if you gave a function prototype for `fun()`, which you really should, then you would get a different set of errors:

```
foo.c:7:25: error: passing 'void' to parameter of incompatible type 'int'
    printf("%d",fun(fun(fun(i))));
                        ^~~~~~
```

Answer (score -1):

Because C is compiled to binary, technically, functions always return a value. With most modern processors, the returned value is saved in a register¹, such as `RAX` (or `EAX` in 32 bit) on an Intel processor, and you just can't remove a register from your CPU.

When you create a void function, the compiler will ignore the result, but it is still there.

In your case, the `fun(fun(fun(i)))`² expression will pass `i` to the first call, then, on an Intel processor on Linux, it will do `MOV RDI, RAX` for the second and third calls. These simply copy the result in `RAX` to the first parameter of the `fun()` function which in assembly is `RDI`.

So this is why your code does *something*. However, today it is considered *Undefined Behavior*. In the old days, when you could make your software work, it was considered a success. Any code that compiled was considered valid code...

---

¹ *On some processors, especially some old 8 bit CPUs, a specific memory location may be used or the caller had to pass an address where the return value had to be written.*

² *Assuming your C compiler accepts such, which it shouldn't. At least gcc 11.3 refused to compile that code.*

Comment: Not every system is a PC with x86/x64 processor. I would say, over all systems programmable in C such systems have a share significantly less than 50%. You might like to change your answer to be more generic. Please consider that not every system has a processor that can return an `int` in a register.

Comment: "*Because C is compiled to binary, technically, functions always return a value.*" -- No, that's not how it works. The code in the question doesn't just have undefined behavior; it violates several constraints, and because that, strictly speaking, it isn't even C. **If** a compiler accepts it, the C standard doesn't define what it does, so in that sense it has undefined behavior. Calling conventions, like returning function results in some particular register, are entirely outside the scope of the C language. C code specifies *behavior*, not CPU instruction sequences.