# My function isn't returning anything but does compile and seems correct

Tags: c

Having a hard time trying to figure out why my code doesn't return anything. I want it to return '3628800' as 10! (factorial). Any help is appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void ft_iterative_factorial(int nb);

int main()
{
    ft_iterative_factorial(10);
    return 0;
}

void ft_iterative_factorial(int nb)
{
    int i;
    int fact;
    int num;

    fact = 1;
    if (num <= 0)
        fact = 1;
    else
    {
        i = 1;
        while (i <= num)
        {
            fact = fact * i;
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Function, function, please return!

Comment: Your function return type is void so no return value. One option for you is change function as int type and return the  fact in your function and then print that returned value in your main function.

Comment: You might like to read this: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C void function with return value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24958014/c-void-function-with-return-value)

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify a return type, so you would have something like this.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int ft_iterative_factorial(int nb);

int main()
{
    int num;
    num = ft_iterative_factorial(10);
    return 0;
}

int ft_iterative_factorial(int nb)
{
    int i;
    int fact;
    int num = nb;

    fact = 1;
    if (num <= 0)
        fact = 1;
    else
    {
        i = 1;
        while (i <= num)
        {
            fact = fact * i;
            i++;
        }
    }

   return fact;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi your function 'ft_iterative_factorial' does not have a return type. Function should have a return type to return some value to the calling function.
Also you are not using the passed parameter 'nb' anywhere in your factorial function.

Here is the corrected code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

//function should have a return value to return something
int ft_iterative_factorial(int nb);

int main()
{
    printf("%d",ft_iterative_factorial(10));
    return 0;
}

int ft_iterative_factorial(int nb)
{
    int i;
    int fact;
    int num = nb;// You have not assigned nb to num
    // In your case num is not initailised

    fact = 1;
    if (num <= 0)
        fact = 1;
    else
    {
        i = 1;
        while (i <= num)
        {
            fact = fact * i;
            i++;
        }
    }
    return fact;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the code compiles, you should simulate the execution of your program step by step:

- the execution enters in `main` function;
- the execution enters in `ft_iterative_factorial`, with argument `10`;
- the variable `fact` is initialized to `1`;
- [...] (computations, that seem to be correct);
- the execution leaves `ft_iterative_factorial`, and therefore discards all variables declared within its scope...

... and here is the problem: the value of `fact` is lost.

If you want that value to be passed back to main function you should for example declare the function `ft_iterative_factorial` as

```cpp
int ft_iterative_factorial(int nb);
```

and add

```cpp
return fact;
```

at the end of its body.

Answer (score 0):

> My function isn't returning anything but does compile and seems
>   correct

Your code is not correct at all. In order to check that just print the value of `fact` inside your `ft_iterative_factorial` function. By change the return type from `void` to `int`, you could solve your return issue but I think you should check the body of `ft_iterative_factorial` carefully.

Hint::

```
void ft_iterative_factorial(int nb) //<---change the return type to int
{
    int i;
    int fact;
    int num;

    fact = 1;
    if (num <= 0)  //<-----what is num????? should be nb
        fact = 1;
    else
    {
        i = 1;
        while (i <= num) //<-----what is num????? should be nb
        {
            fact = fact * i;
            i++;
        }
    }
           //<------ just add return statement

}
```